# Comparing models - accuracy vs. recall

Tags: predictive-models, accuracy, precision-recall, weka

I'm using Weka to generate many models using different functions (`Logistic`, `MultilayerPerceptron`, `SMO`, etc.)

I'm asked to compare these models. My question is - should I compare them by accuracy or recall? I think I read somewhere that recall is more meaningful when comparing models, so I would like to confirm this.

Comment: What is your goal for the final model? Eg, is it for a screening test? Is one type of error more costly that the other?

Comment: Thank you @gung. I'm a Statistics student and I was given a dataset with thousands of purchases from a grocery store. I'm asked to predict whether a customer will buy an organic product or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm following the line hinted in @gung's comment.

You should compare a model by its goal.
The goal of a model is not a question os machine learning or statistic, in is question of the business domain and its needs.

Accuracy is a very common and useful measure. However, if you are dealing with fraud the model "Everybody are OK" will have very high accuracy. That high accuracy will be misleading since the model is useless for fraud detection.

If you are digging for gold (a scenario in which you have huge benefit from a true positive, not too high cost of a false positive) then recall is a good measure.

If you are trying to decide whether to perform a complex medical procedure on people (high cost of false positive, hopefully a low cost of false negative), precision is the measure you should use.

Comment: Thank you @Dan Levin, your answer was very insightful. I'm a Statistics student and I was given a dataset with thousands of purchases from a grocery store. I'm asked to predict whether a customer will buy an organic product or not. So following your answer, it seems like accuracy would be a good measurement to compare models.

Comment: Accuracy will be OK here but you might take it a bit further. 

You can put a weight on false negative (customer that would have bought organic food). This cost should be something like the extra cost of organic food over a year.
Then you should put a cost on the false positives (customers that won't buy organic food though predicted to do so). The cost can be discounts given to them.

Now you should choose the model which is optimal with respect to the costs.
Doing that will probably get you some extra points ;-)